# with the datetimepicker in vb.net i can set the custom format no hitch but cant get it to hold that format in the .value property?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

```
Try
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    ' Display the date as "2012-10-24 21:47:09".
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    strQuery = "INSERT INTO TimeClockInfo(IdTimeClock, First_Name, Last_Name, LogTime, In_Out) VALUES('" & AddTimeEmplyIdBox.Text & "','" & AddTimeEmplyFNBox.Text & "','" & AddTimeEmplyLNBox.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "','in')"

    SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)

    dbCon.Open()

    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    dbCon.Close()
    MsgBox("TimeClock Data Added Successfully!")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Failure!", ex.Message)
End Try
```

this returns the original format of the date and time in the value property? what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTimePicker1.Value` is a `DateTime` - it doesn't have an inherent format.

If you want to format it, use `ToString` with a Date and Time format string of your choice.

MSDN details the [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) format strings.

However, since you are interacting with SQL, you shouldn't be concatenating SQL - your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) this way. You should use parameterized SQL, which doesn't have this vulnerability and will deal with the `DateTime` correctly as well.

Comment: Ok, so your saying that the datetimepicker1.format only changes the format displayed in the program? and that i need to format the value in a format string? what would be the best way to do this giving my code? and ty for the fast response btw :)

Comment: @Aaron - Yes. When you pick a date, the picker creates a corresponding `DateTime` instance. However, you should be using parameterized SQL instead of constructing SQL in a string - it is vulnerable.

Comment: ok thankyou for your help. and i will look into the code issue as well.